# AJAX PUT request is not working within CasperJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, casperjs, put

I am implementing a scrapping script with CASPERJS which is also using some AJAX jquery calls as the one below which should POST to TRELLO:

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/mycardid?name=Thursday%20-%20%C2%A300000&key=mykey&token=mytoken",
  "method": "PUT",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
   }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

I have a similar function wrapped into `casper.evaluate(function(){})` which is performing a get request and working as expected. I tried PUT-ing via Postman and all worked fine, but I cannot get the call to work with casperJS, wrapped into an evaluate function, which is supposed to run javascript. Is there anything I missed, such as: Casper cannot run put requests to APIs?

Comment: What's logged from `console.log(response)`?

Comment: Nothing, as casper is not logging anything in an evaluate, so that's my frustration, that I cannot see that output

Comment: add a `fail` handler and inspect jqXhr object

Comment: Can you please give an example of the above? It is literally my first day of AJAX calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer is here:

```
  return $.ajax({
  type: "PUT",
  async: false,
  url: "urlasabove",
  body: {}
});
```

The correct answer is to put `key: "value"` rather than `string: string`

Comment: Well, this is working, but now I am not sure why the call works for just up to 5 requests, once I have 6 items in the array the phantomJS is blowing with a "cannot process command"